# How to retrieve date from SQL server datetime column and store in php variable?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve the date only from my table and store it in a php variable so I can echo it out where and when I want. Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
$query3 = "select o.orderID,
o.orderDate

from orders o
join order_items i on o.orderID = i.orderID
where o.customerID = '" . $customerID . "'";

    $result3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query3, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

if( $result3 === false)
{
    echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $data1 = $row['orderDate']; 
    }

echo $data1;
```

I have experimented with the date() method and I can get a date on the screen but not a specific one selected from the database. Do I need to convert this before I echo it?

The error I am getting is this:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Thank you.

Comment: What _does_ `echo $data1` output?

Comment: At the moment nothing, I get an error as the page doesn't load past the area of where I am trying to output this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 
        $data1 = $row['orderDate'];  
    } 

echo $data1;
```

works through each line of your result, but will only show if relevant the last one. Is this perhaps your issue?

Comment: I have more code than this, it outputs everything on an order by a customer, I just posted the code I am having issues with to keep the question simple. When I try and echo the above variable it has an issue because I don't think I can just store a date time format into an array and then into a variable. I somehow need to take the date convert it into a string then store it in the variable?

Thanks

Comment: I have included the error as found in the error reporting, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a [DateTime](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, as the error message suggests:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's a native PHP variable with a date. The driver does it for you!

Comment: So what is the best way to display this on the screen, just the date no time?

Thank you!

Comment: The best way to display a `DateTime` as string is the [format()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

Comment: I have the impression that you haven't understood my answer... :(

Comment: I am sorry, I did kind of understand it, but not enough to get it to work, I did try and figure it out, but I guess I needed more help!

I appreciate your help though!!!